# Any way to shorten syntax when using class interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wpf

Let's say I have created a Slider User Control which implements ISlider Interface. I have some methods like SetValue below which should accept both ISlider types and standard Slider control type. Am I'm obliged to use this heavy syntax is there any shortcut ?

```
    public void SetValue(Object slider, Double value) {
    ISlider ISlider;
    ISlider = slider as ISlider;
    if (ISlider != null)
    {
        ISlider.Value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        ((Slider)slider).Value = value;
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Slider` implement `ISlider`? Alternatively, why don't you provide an implementation of `ISlider` that wraps a `Slider` so that you only have to deal with the interface.

Comment: because Slider is a Microsoft standard control. As far as I know I cannot extend such control with class interface maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: That's why I said "alternatively, provide an implementation of ISlider that wraps a Slider".

Comment: That's what I'm doing but still my method should continue to work with standard control so my question :)

Comment: I think you're missing my point. If you had an adapter that wraps a `Slider` and implements `ISlider`, you would pass the *adapter instance* to your methods and your methods would therefore work against a `Slider` by virtue of the adapter.

Comment: OK but in truth I have simplified the case It's rather ISlider.SetValue and not ISlider.Value so methods not exactly same and also I can't see in practice how to create an adaptater that is not a UserControl. Sorry I'm beginner so maybe I cannot understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't make the wpf `Slider` control inherit from your `ISlider`, use an overloaded method.

```
public void SetValue(ISlider slider, double value)
{
    slider.Value = value;
}

public void SetValue(Slider slider, double value)
{
    slider.Value = value;
}
```

This isn't pretty, but saves you a headache as you don't have to check if the object is the correct type.

Comment: And how is that helping with the OP's code? since the variable is `object` overload resolution isn't available.

Comment: I assumed that he supplies `Slider` or `ISlider` instances to the method. If he would supply `object` however, you are correct. Considering he accepted my answer, my assumption appears to have been correct.